# Why is find exec grep > file an Infinite Loop?

Tags: linux, find, grep, redirection, exec

I was trying to collect all of the Message-ID: headers (lines) in a directory with 200K .eml (plain text) files. A bit naively, I said:

```
find -type f -exec grep -Fi "message-id:" {} \; > messageids.txt
```

I let it run overnight, since I figured it would take a while to grep through that many files. A bit to my surprise this morning, messageids.txt is 1.7TB and my partition is full. I realize that what must have happened is that grep's own output is being picked up as input, but I wouldn't (and still don't, intuitively) expect it to repeat endlessly. Which means that my understanding of the forces at play isn't as strong as it should be.

Can anyone provide a detailed explanation of how the command above works and why this infinite loop should (I assume) be expected? Thanks.

Update:
The way I'd expect it to work is that find finds a list of files, and on each one of them grep is called. So at some point grep is called on messageids.txt. If I were to do this on, say, a sort command, messageids.txt would be created as soon as the command executes (possibly whacking it, if it already existed), but it wouldn't be populated until the command completes. In this case, for the loop to be infinite, the file must be getting populated before the output is complete, but in such a way that the input from grep is perpetually keeping up on it. That's the bit that doesn't behave like I'd expect, and I was hoping for a detailed explanation of how this process chain is executing so I can firm up my Linux fundamentals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time it finds a line with `message-id` in it, it soon writes it to `messageids.txt`. And every time it writes a line with `message-id` in it to `messageids.txt`, it soon finds it. So this is a trivial endless loop.

Comment: And here's how to circumvent it: `find -type f ! -name messageids.txt -exec grep -Fi "message-id:" {} \; > messageids.txt`

Comment: I understand that that is -what- is happening, but I don't understand -why- it's happening. Clearly my understanding of either find or grep or redirects isn't perfect, but I'm not sure which one was surprising me. So I was hoping for a detailed explanation of the whole command. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: @HammerBro. The output needs to be stored somewhere. RAM is expensive, and temp files are unnecessary if you just write to the file anyway. Unless you actively prevent it from writing immediately, it just does. Why shouldn't it? It's also immediately writing to the terminal if you don't redirect the output.

Comment: @DanielBeck "Why shouldn't it?" That's a good point. I'm still not sure why my intuitions on the matter are so confused; I think I'm mixing pipes with redirects on some level. But that should put the matter to rest well enough. Thanks for the helpful commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested something like this and it worked.

`for f in $(find . -type f); do grep -Fi "message-id:" $f > messageids.txt; done`

Comment: It probably depends on your output write caching, and how soon in the loop the output file is hit.

Comment: I'm not looking for how to get around the issue -- I can modify find or the output location in a number of ways. I'm looking for a low level explanation as to why this gets picked up as an infinite loop; I'll update the question with greater details.